# Selecting the Max Value from Each Unique Day for Multiple Locations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure (note the headers are actually all caps):

```
Start_Date | Hour | Item | Location | ... | Numerical Metrics ... |
-----------|------|------|----------|-----|-----------------------|
8/6/19     |  0   |   A  |    USE   | ... | (numbers that I want  |
8/6/19     |  0   |   B  |    USE   | ... |  to get the max of)   |
8/6/19     |  0   |   C  |    USW   | ... |                       |
8/6/19     |  0   |   D  |    USW   | ... |                       |
8/6/19     |  1   |   A  |    USE   | ... |                       |
8/6/19     |  1   |   B  |    USE   | ... |                       |
8/6/19     |  1   |   C  |    USW   | ... |                       |
8/6/19     |  1   |   D  |    USW   | ... |                       |
.....
8/1/19     |  23  |   D  |    USW   | ... |                       |
```

This continues, Hours 0 - 23 (4x each; 1x for each item) for every date. So there's 96 data points (rows) per day

I'm trying to query (or create a new table) and present the max data from the numerical metrics for each unique day for each item. So if I had the dates: 8/1/19 -> 8/6/19, I currently have 576 rows, but I'm trying to break that down to the 4 for each day, or 24 rows.

I'm currently just trying to get the max for each specific day (so not even worried about the Item portion yet -- which I can't get either) but when I put MAX in my SELECT statements I'm only getting 1 result overall. So I'm having a hard time figuring out how to "loop" through all dates and grab each one. I'm tried `UNIQUE Start_Date` to see if that would give me a max for each date, but that didn't work either.

```
SELECT START_DATE,
       HOUR,
       ITEM,
       LOCATION,
       SERVICE,
       MAX(SALES)                            as SALES,
       MAX(ITEMS)                             as ITEMS,
       MAX(PRICE)                              as PRICE,
FROM newtable
WHERE ITEM IN (
        SELECT ITEM
        FROM newtable
        WHERE START_DATE IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT START_DATE
                FROM newtable
        )
);
```

The results I would be looking for are:

```
Start_Date | Item | Location | ... | Numerical Metrics ... |
-----------|------|----------|-----|-----------------------|
8/6/19     |   A  |    USE   | ... | (max numbers from     |
8/6/19     |   B  |    USE   | ... |  that day are shown)  |
8/6/19     |   C  |    USW   | ... |                       |
8/6/19     |   D  |    USW   | ... |                       |
8/5/19     |   A  |    USE   | ... |                       |
```

we can rid of the hour table since I no longer care about it, the goal is to obtain a daily metric

The current result is just the first row:

```
Start_Date | Item | Location | ... | Numerical Metrics ... |
-----------|------|----------|-----|-----------------------|
8/6/19     |   A  |    USE   | ... | max from that day     |
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: You have four columns.  What do you want the max of?

Comment: I think you just need add `GROUP BY Start_Date, Item` at the end?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Most recent... Is that 8?

Comment: @GordonLinoff If you see in my SELECT statement, I have numerical metrics I'm trying to get for the max of that day (sales, items, price)

Comment: What I don't understand is why you have location on the query. You can have max sales in `USE` but max price in `USW` so not sure what is your expected result. Please include some example with metrics and expected result. Also, you have `Service` but didn't show it on the sample data but probably will have same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to query (or create a new table) and present the max data from the numerical metrics for each unique day for each item.

This is an aggregation query:

```
SELECT START_DATE, ITEM,
       MAX(SALES) as SALES,
       MAX(ITEMS as ITEMS,
       MAX(PRICE) as PRICE
FROM newtable
GROUP BY START_DATE, ITEM;
```

Including the location and other (non-aggregated) columns doesn't make sense for the question you are asking.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I didn't come up with that... I guess the tricky part is now how I parse it into months for the purpose of getting the top 10 sellers in each specific month (as an example).